Cloud Run -> Cloud Run connection via Internal ingress
This is a follow-up question for:
Deny direct access to Google Cloud Run/Functions and allow via Loadbalancer
As described here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/private-networking#from-other-services - it is not trivial just to enable internal and loadbalancer traffic as communication between Cloud Functions and Cloud Runs between each other are not considered internal by default.
This document describes very briefly three options:

Configure the source service to send all traffic through the VPC network and enable Private Google Access on the subnet associated with Direct VPC egress or the connector.
Set up Private Service Connect or an internal Application Load Balancer to front your destination Cloud Run service. With this configuration, you access Cloud Run by using internal IP addresses, so requests are routed through the VPC network.
Enable Private Google Access on the subnet associated with the source service and configure DNS to resolve run.app URLs to the private.googleapis.com (199.36.153.8/30) or restricted.googleapis.com (199.36.153.4/30) ranges. Requests to these ranges are routed through the VPC network.

However it is not clear what is preferred/simplest solution and there is no clear instructions how to perform these.
So what would be the easiest and most straightforward way to really achieve internal and loadbalancer traffic?

Refer this Medium Blog By Murli Krishnan which may helps to resolve your issue

Shared VPC are now supported without internal LB as described in the documentation. In fact, the problem is the following: *.run.app URL is only resolvable publicly. So, either (option 1) you  route all the traffic through the VPC connector (or direct VPC egress) to go through the VPC for public and private IP. Or (option 3) you configure your DNS to use Private Google Access. Last option, the 2, you put something internal with private IP on top of cloud run, an internal LB, and this time, no problem with public IP/DNS resolution and a VPC connector with default config is enough.

Thanks. From the article by Murli and what Guillaume writes, I guess the most straightforward way is to configure the source service to send all trafice through the VPC. From the article - is really the only required thing to do the "Enforced mode perimeter"?
